# Player Controls are different on different user agents

Tags: mediaelement.js

I use mediaelement for the first time on an artists page.
I'm not able to use the nice looking control (control.png)

The controls are different with all the different browser versions.
(Opera, IE, FF, Chrome, Safari)
So I think I made a mistake and each browser uses the default html5 controls from it's own stylesheet.

I added in the header:

```
  <link href="mediaelementplayer.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fullscreenapi.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
```

Then there comes some script:

```
</head>
<script>
// using jQuery
//$('video,audio').mediaelementplayer(/* Options */);

$('video').mediaelementplayer('player', {
// if the <video width> is not specified, this is the default
defaultVideoWidth: 598,
// if the <video height> is not specified, this is the default
defaultVideoHeight: 478,
// if set, overrides <video width>
videoWidth: -1,
// if set, overrides <video height>
videoHeight: -1,
// width of audio player
audioWidth: 400,
// height of audio player
audioHeight: 30,
// initial volume when the player starts
startVolume: 0.8,
// useful for <audio> player loops
loop: false,
// enables Flash and Silverlight to resize to content size
enableAutosize: true,
// the order of controls you want on the control bar (and other plugins below)
features: ['playpause', 'loop', 'progress','current','duration','tracks','volume','fullscreen'],
// Hide controls when playing and mouse is not over the video
alwaysShowControls: false,
// force iPad's native controls
iPadUseNativeControls: false,
// force iPhone's native controls
iPhoneUseNativeControls: false,
// force Android's native controls
AndroidUseNativeControls: false,
// forces the hour marker (##:00:00)
alwaysShowHours: false,
// show framecount in timecode (##:00:00:00)
showTimecodeFrameCount: false,
// used when showTimecodeFrameCount is set to true
framesPerSecond: 25,
// turns keyboard support on and off for this instance
enableKeyboard: true,
// when this player starts, it will pause other players
pauseOtherPlayers: true,
// array of keyboard commands
keyActions: []

 });

 </script>
 <body id="archive">
```

And finally the video:

```
 <div class="video">

 <video id="player" width="598" height="478" poster="poster.png" controls="controls" preload="none">
 <!-- MP4 for Safari, IE9, iPhone, iPad, Android, and Windows Phone 7 -->
 <source type="video/mp4" src="rot.mp4" />
 <!-- WebM/VP8 for Firefox4, Opera, and Chrome -->
 <source type="video/webm" src="rot.webm" />
 <!-- Ogg/Vorbis for older Firefox and Opera versions -->
 <source type="video/ogg" src="rot.ogv" />
 <!-- Optional: Add subtitles for each language -->
 <!-- track kind="subtitles" src="subtitles.srt" srclang="en" / -->
 <!-- Optional: Add chapters -->
 <!-- track kind="chapters" src="chapters.srt" srclang="en" / -->
 <!-- Flash fallback for non-HTML5 browsers without JavaScript -->
 <object width="598" height="478" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flashmediaelement.swf">
     <param name="movie" value="flashmediaelement.swf" />
    <param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&file=rot.mp4" />
    <!-- Image as a last resort -->
    <img src="poster2.png" width="598" height="478" title="No video playback capabilities" />
 </object>
 </video>
 </div>
```

can anybody see, where's my fault?
Thank you
Tom

Comment: sorry for pushing - any idea?

Comment: Is it at all possible that it's hitting the fallback flash/silverlight versions?  I recall reading those fall back to a default.

Answer (score -1):

You must reference to the mediaelementplayer.min.css in yout html document.